# How to assign UIImageView delegate to its super UIView so that it can know which UIImageView is touched

Tags: objective-c

I have several UIImageViews contained by a UIView. My idea is when a UIImageView is touched, the UIView can know which one is touched thru delegate.
Here's my code
MyImageView.h

```
@protocol MyImageViewDelegate
  -(void)toucheDelegate:(id)sender;
@end

@interface MyImageView:UIImageView{
  id<MyImageViewDelegate> delegate;
}

@property(assign) id<MyImageViewDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

MyImageView.h

```
@implementation MyImageView
@synthesize delegate

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  [self.delegate touchDelegate:self];
}
```

MyView.m

```
-(void)functionA{
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    MyImageView *imageView=[[MyImageView alloc] init];
    imageView.delegate=self;  //Here it gives a warning saying Assigning to 'id<MyImageViewDelegate>' from incompatible type 'MyView *'
    [self addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
  }
}

-(void)touchDelegate:(id)sender{
  NSLog(@"in superview");
}
```

The exception is unrecognized seletor sent to instance 0x7526c30. What does this mean?
I'm new to objective c and I'm not very clear about this delegate thing or the warning I mentioned in the code block. What's the problem? Any suggestion?

Comment: In your MyView.h file make sure you have this: MyView : WhatYoureInheritingFrom<MyImageViewDelegate>

Comment: What is the complete "unrecognized selector" error message?

Comment: UIImageview cannot accept taps by default. It's userInteractionEnabled it set to NO. You can change it to yes and try.

Comment: @Violet Check my answer. I have used `UITapGestureRecognizer`. to recognize tap on UIImageView.

Comment: @Violet Also, "unrecognized seletor sent to instance" means you're calling a method (sending a selector) on an object (instance) that doesn't have that method.  Because of the warning, I'm pretty sure your delegation isn't wired correctly.  This will cause your method [self.delegate touchDelegate:self]; to throw the exception that you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Implement in this way

Create and Image then enable `userInteraction` by `[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]` Then add tag and Give `UITapGestureRecognizer` with a selector that's all you need to doo.

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    MyImageView *imageView=[[MyImageView alloc] init];
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    [self.imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete.png"]];
    [self.imageView setTag:i];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imgTouchUp:)];
    tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
}
```

Then In selector recognize UIImaged taped by their respective **Tags** which can be found as shown bellow.

```
-(void) imgTouchUp:(id)sender {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender;
    NSLog(@"Taped Image tag is %d", gesture.view.tag);
}
```

You can Also find various Gestures.

1. [UITapGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITapGestureRecognizer).
2. [UIPinchGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPinchGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPinchGestureRecognizer).
3. [UIRotationGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIRotateGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIRotationGestureRecognizer).
4. [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISwipeGestureRecognizer).
5. [UIPanGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPanGestureRecognizer).
6. [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILongPressGestureRecognizer).

Comment: This looks much better than implementing touchesBegan. But If I want to move the touched imageview, I still need to write code in imgTouchUp as what I did in touchesMoved right?

Comment: And what if I want to do something at touch begin point and end point by using UIGestureRecognizer?

Comment: @Violet I have Updated My answer Have A look at it.